# java and C# libraries for wi-fi

Tags: c#, java, libraries, wifi

here is a tough question :D
can anyone tell me the names of libraries concerning Wi-Fi as i want to build a mobile application that can connect to a local server through wi-fi and exchange information with it.
also i want to know which library is better and which language too ??
thanks in advance

Comment: An application (mobile or not) usually doesn't need to know what type of internet connection is set (wired, wifi, 3G, etc.): the internet connection is managed by the OS.

From your application (java or .net), you use abstract APIs (sockets, ftp, http, webservices, etc.) that rely on this os-managed connection, without needing to know it.

Comment: You want to be able to select a way of making connection from hand held device directly from your app? If you think Java for that, imposibru! User must select one of the possible connections among which is WiFi and allow app to use it for that session or that one time.

Answer (score 0):

for Java, I googled:
http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/FAQ.html

see also:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706783.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/

got that from: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/811865-c-newbie-wifi-programming